# What is the inverse of OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, io

An OutputStreamWriter wraps an OutputStream behind a Writer interface. What if I want the inverse, I want an OutputStream interface to a Writer? For instance I want to serialize an object to a StringWriter.

Comment: An `OutputStreamWriter` _writes_ to an `OutputStream`. A writer writes. You cannot write to it. You could however write to a `BinaryOutputStream`, get the bytes and convert them to `String` if that's what you mean

Comment: Can you show example of code what you want to achieve? It's not clear why you need it.

Comment: @LewsTherin Why would WriterOutputStream not make sense? The Java API is full of wrapper classes that can be combined in various ways. Could you elaborate your point please?

Comment: @Mishax Well, if I was to *try* to read & understand it, it will end up as "writing to an outputstream". Thus, essentially the same as `OutputStreamWriter`. Grammatically, it isn't correct.

Comment: @c.s. I don't understand why the downvote? Of course you write to writers, the Java API doc shows the example 'new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")))'

Comment: @Mishax That's passing an argument to a Writer. That's not the same thing as writing to a writer. I guess I could write to Robert Jordan though...

Comment: Such a thing would allow binary data to be represented as characters. This is usually done using methods like hex or base64 encoding. There are implementations doing just this.

Comment: @LewsTherin I don't understand why all the downvotes? And no, an OutputStreamWriter "writes to an outputstream". I am trying to do the inverse, namely write bytes (what an outputstream does) to a character-oriented Writer.

Comment: @Mishax I haven't downvoted :) I repeat a writer writes. `FileWriter` writes to a file in the case you mentioned. You don't write to the writer. You are confused about who is performing an action on a resource and which is the resource. Streams, files are resources. Writers manipulate them

Comment: @Mishax  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html Is that what you want?

Comment: @LewsTherin A StringWriter is a Writer. Great. Now suppose I have an ObjectOutputStream and I want to sent the output to a StringWriter. (or any other writer). All I am asking is what is the way to accomplish that. If I had a Writer and wanted to write to an OutputStream, I would use an OutputStreamWriter. I am just trying to solve the opposite situation, where I have an OutputStream and want that to output to a writer.

Comment: @Mishax Well you will have to read the data from the source and pass the data to StringWriter. Look at the API for StringWriter, it takes a character array and 2 more args.

Comment: [Commons IO WriterOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/WriterOutputStream.html) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantic of an `OutputStreamWriter` is to take text and transform it according to a character encoding to bytes. This is a very common pattern (low level bytes interpreted as high level text) so it isn't surprising to find this class as part of the standard Java API.

So you want a `WriterOutputStream`. But you forgot to tell us about the semantics you expect for such a class. I can imagine several use cases for an `OutputStream` wrapping a `Writer`:

- Convert the bytes to a Base64 encoded string
- Convert the bytes to a table of hex values
- Assuming the byte stream is an encrypted text message: Decrypt the bytes and write the original unencrypted text.
- Assuming the byte stream are the values of some kind of measuring device: Write a human readable table containing the measured values.

But there is no obvious default use case which makes sense for a broad usage. So there is no `WriterOutputStream` class in the standard library. But no one prevents you to write such a class of your own.

Comment: Well, vanje you have a point but on the other hand OutputStreamWriter declares a constructor that accepts an OutputStream, in which "default character encoding" is applied. If the API supports conversion of a byte-oriented stream to a character-oriented stream according to a certain default, should I not expect that I could do the inverse, also with such a default? Since the API does not have a WriterOutputStream, what is the simplest workaround? This is what I am (still) searching for.

Comment: @Mishax: The simplest workaround is to write your bytes to a ByteArrayOutputStream, and call toString() with the appropriate charset name as argument.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree if your goal is nothing more than a String. But if the goal is a Writer that means starting with an outputstream, (1) then sending that to a ByteArrayOutputStream, (2) then toString() that, (3) create a Writer (4) Write my String to that. Whew! If this is the simplest workaround then okay but of course something like your Guava class is a lot simpler.

Comment: @Mishax: Could you describe your actual, concrete use-case for this, because we have too much to guess: what should the WriterOutputStream do, where do you want to write, etc. It starts to look like an XY problem.

Comment: @Mishax: The default use case to convert text to bytes is to apply a character encoding because it is so common. This is totally unrelated to the possibility to omit an explicit encoding so that a default character encoding is used. (Btw. you should never rely on the default encoding because it depends on the OS.) But there is no common use case for a conversion of bytes to text. What should it be? So I think you cannot expect a default bytes to text conversion. If you're missing one then implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Guava has such a class : [BaseEncoding.encodingStream(Writer)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#encodingStream%28java.io.Writer%29) takes a Writer as argument, and wraps it in an OutputStream. All the bytes written to the stream are baseXX-encoded (where XX can be 16, 32, 64, ...) and written as characters to the wrapped Writer.